# A scrollbar event when scrolling?

Tags: c++, python, qt, events, pyqt

I need an event for detecting if an user has moved the scrollbar position to another one.

In other words, if the user does scroll up/down, would it be possible to catch a signal so I can know the scroll has been changed its position?

I think it's not important, but the scrollbar I refer to is inside a `QGraphicsView`.

Regards.

**Edit:**

`QGraphicsView` is for displaying items in the screen, and if those items are too big it shows the scrollbars I refer to. What I need is to know when the user changes the position of those scrollbars.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sliders have a `sliderMoved(int value)` signal, where value is the new position of slider.

Comment: I've read this page (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qslider.html), but it's not into QGraphicsView. The difference between those two is that QSlider seems to be used for things like a slider for a videoplayer, or things like that. QGraphicsView is for displaying items in the screen, and if those items are too big it shows the scrollbars I refer to. What I need is to know when the user changes the position of those scrollbars.

Comment: Don't you have access to horizontalScrollBar and verticalScrollBar from QGraphicsView?

Comment: Oh, yeah. You're right my friend. I've been able to do what I wanted accessing to it with the verticalScrollBar() method. I've used its "valueChanged()" signal. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get notified when the scroll bar position is changed, you need to subclass the `QGraphicsView` and reimplement the `QWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent*)`. For this you also need to enable mouse tracking. [Here is Qt 4.7 QGraphicsView reference.](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qgraphicsview.html#mouseMoveEvent)

Comment: The solution was accessing to the scrollbars with its methods and using the signals I was looking for, as I've said in another post. Anyway, thanks for your answer ^^.